# Align Disaggregated Data in R

Tags: r

I have an excel data set in excel that I would like to load into R. The dataset has two variables "weight" and "height" in which each variable has its own date specified as to when it was recorded. The height variable has skipping/missing values, likewise in the weight variable if you go down in the data far enough. I am trying to create a consolidated data-set in which weight and height are combined and arranged by the date in the proper place and NA's are placed when a value isn't present. Are there any commands/functions that can help me do this? Thank you!

```
 obs     date   weight     date    height
  1   2010-10-04 52495  2010-10-04 11.6  
  2   2010-10-01 53000  2010-10-01 15.3
  3   2010-09-30 52916  2010-09-30 14.3
  4   2010-09-29 52785  2010-09-29 11.3
  5   2010-09-28 53348  2010-09-28 18.2
  6   2010-09-27 52885  2010-09-24 11.7
  7   2010-09-24 52174  2010-09-23 15.0
  8   2010-09-23 51461  2010-09-22 18.6
  9   2010-09-22 51286  2010-09-20 17.9
  10  2010-09-21 50968  
  11  2010-09-20 49250
```

Comment: Is it convenient to load these as two data frames?  That would make things easier.

Comment: If this had been presented from an R object that had been read in with read.table, there would _not_ have been duplicate column names. @gabriel: please learn to post the output of `dput(r_object)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d <- read.table(header=FALSE, fill=TRUE, text="1   2010-10-04 52495  2010-10-04 11.6  
  2   2010-10-01 53000  2010-10-01 15.3
  3   2010-09-30 52916  2010-09-30 14.3
  4   2010-09-29 52785  2010-09-29 11.3
  5   2010-09-28 53348  2010-09-28 18.2
  6   2010-09-27 52885  2010-09-24 11.7
  7   2010-09-24 52174  2010-09-23 15.0
  8   2010-09-23 51461  2010-09-22 18.6
  9   2010-09-22 51286  2010-09-20 17.9
  10  2010-09-21 50968  
  11  2010-09-20 49250  ")

d1 <- d[2:3]
d2 <- d[!is.na(d[,5]),][4:5]

names(d1) <- c('Date', 'val1')
names(d2) <- c('Date', 'val2')
m <- merge(d1, d2, by='Date', all=TRUE)

> m

##          Date  val1 val2
## 1  2010-09-20 49250 17.9
## 2  2010-09-21 50968   NA
## 3  2010-09-22 51286 18.6
## 4  2010-09-23 51461 15.0
## 5  2010-09-24 52174 11.7
## 6  2010-09-27 52885   NA
## 7  2010-09-28 53348 18.2
## 8  2010-09-29 52785 11.3
## 9  2010-09-30 52916 14.3
## 10 2010-10-01 53000 15.3
## 11 2010-10-04 52495 11.6
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this question isn't about reading the data into R, but processing it after it has been read. Nevertheless, you can use the arguments `check.names = FALSE` and `fill = TRUE` when reading your data in to allow you to use `Reduce` to merge your data.

First, simulate reading the data in.

```
temp <- read.table(header = TRUE, 
text = "obs date weight date height
1   2010-10-04 52495  2010-10-04 11.6
2   2010-10-01 53000  2010-10-01 15.3
3   2010-09-30 52916  2010-09-30 14.3
4   2010-09-29 52785  2010-09-29 11.3
5   2010-09-28 53348  2010-09-28 18.2
6   2010-09-27 52885  2010-09-24 11.7
7   2010-09-24 52174  2010-09-23 15.0
8   2010-09-23 51461  2010-09-22 18.6
9   2010-09-22 51286  2010-09-20 17.9
10  2010-09-21 50968
11  2010-09-20 49250
", fill = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
```

Second, use `Reduce()` and `merge()`.

```
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all.x = TRUE), 
       list(temp[2:3], temp[4:5]))
#          date weight height
# 1  2010-09-20  49250   17.9
# 2  2010-09-21  50968     NA
# 3  2010-09-22  51286   18.6
# 4  2010-09-23  51461   15.0
# 5  2010-09-24  52174   11.7
# 6  2010-09-27  52885     NA
# 7  2010-09-28  53348   18.2
# 8  2010-09-29  52785   11.3
# 9  2010-09-30  52916   14.3
# 10 2010-10-01  53000   15.3
# 11 2010-10-04  52495   11.6
```

Comment: `Reduce` seems to be overkill here: `merge(temp[2:3], temp[4:5], all.x=TRUE)`.  But perhaps there are more than two pairs of columns.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, yeah, you're totally right. For this particular example, it is overkill. I was thinking of potentially more columns, but re-reading the question, I doubt it!